# Converting xls to csv in python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I've successfully converted xls to csv, but I've a problem. It seems normal in the csv file itself but when I run the output, everything is wrong.

```
changeWb = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
sh = changeWb.sheet_by_name('detail')
csv_file = open('test2.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
    wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in sh.row_values(rownum)])
csv_file.close()
```

I don't have any csv files at the start, opening a csv_file is actually opening a new file freshly.
The old output was:

```
['001', '1387533864.0', '1387575618.0']
['003', '1387534098.0', '1387573600.0']
```

I need something like:

```
['1', '1387533864', '1387575618']    
['3', '1387534098', '1387573600']
```

The bottom output is after I goes into the file, and save as csv(comma delimted).
Please advice on how I can get the bottom result using python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conver the values to `int` first:

```
wr.writerow(sh.row_values(0))
for rownum in xrange(1, sh.nrows):
    wr.writerow([str(int(entry)) for entry in sh.row_values(rownum)])
    #                ^^^
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
My `row 1` is actually `string`, followed by int from `row 2` onwards, so I can't convert all values into `int`

Comment: @VickPeh, Write header outside the loop. I updated the answer code.

Comment: this is the error I received:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1387533864.0'`

Comment: @VickPeh, How about `str(int(float(entry)))` instead of  `str(int(entry))`?

Comment: @VickPeh, If `entry` is all string, you can use `entry.partition('.')[0]`

Comment: I can't use `[unicode(entry).encode("utf-8")]` infront as it set a format as base 10 instead of int.

Comment: Earlier on, I used unicode as to prevent all the decimals from appearing. Since changing it to int solve the issue, I can remove the unicode. (:

Comment: How did you solve the problem @VickPeh ? I'm using `unicode(entry)` and I've the same problem as you had.